# Apache Zeppelin ZeppelinContext not working as expected

Tags: bash, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-zeppelin

**Environment**: AWS EMR with Apache Zeppelin 0.8.2

I have a Zeppelin notebook with different interpreter paragraphs that use `ZeppelinContext` to exchange some configuration data as described in the [documentation](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.8.2/interpreter/shell.html).

As per the documentation, I turn on Shell Interpolation (1st paragraph):

```
%sh.conf

# Permitir que a shell aceda a shared objects (i.e: configurações)

zeppelin.shell.interpolation true
```

Then I set objects in ZeppelinContext (2nd paragraph):

```
%pyspark

# Configurações

z.put("bucket_name", "s3://xxxxxxx/")
z.put("init_k", 60)
z.put("last_k", 330)
z.put("step", 30)
z.put("max_iter", 50)
z.put("tol", 1.0e-5)
z.put("verbose", False)
z.put("score_method", "silhouette_score")
z.put("samplesize", "100000")
z.put("anomaly_threshold", 100)
```

Then I try to read from a `%sh` paragraph (3rd paragraph):

```
%sh

BUCKET_NAME={bucket_name}
SAMPLE_SIZE={samplesize}

echo {bucket_name}
echo $BUCKET_NAME
echo $SAMPLE_SIZE
```

Output:

```
s3://xxxxxxx/  
s3://xxxxxxx/  
100000
```

So it works like this, but then I try to do something else, it fails to resolve the variables. I used exactly the same referencing style (4th paragraph):

```
%sh

BUCKET_NAME={bucket_name}
SAMPLE_SIZE={samplesize}

echo {bucket_name}
echo $BUCKET_NAME
echo $SAMPLE_SIZE

# Sacar o training dataset e fazer upload para o S3

wget -nv http://kdd.ics.uci.edu/databases/kddcup99/kddcup.data_10_percent.gz
gunzip kddcup.data_10_percent.gz
aws s3 cp kddcup.data_10_percent $BUCKET_NAME

# Sacar full data para predicoes

wget -nv http://kdd.ics.uci.edu/databases/kddcup99/kddcup.data.gz
gunzip kddcup.data.gz
aws s3 cp kddcup.data $BUCKET_NAME

ROW_COUNT="$(wc -l kddcup.data | awk '{print $1}')"

if ! [ $ROW_COUNT -ge $SAMPLE_SIZE ]; then 
    echo Please provide a lower sample size; 
    echo exit 2;  
else
    shuf -n $SAMPLE_SIZE kddcup.data > kddcup_sample_1.data
    aws s3 cp kddcup_sample_1.data $BUCKET_NAME
fi  

# Limpeza

rm kddcup.data kddcup.data_10_percent kddcup_sample_1.data
```

Output:

```
{bucket_name}  
{bucket_name}  
{samplesize} 

(bunch of errors because variables were not set)
```

On the same 4th paragraph, if I simply remove everything below the `echo` lines it works again.

The `%sh` interpreter must be having some problem evaluating `ZeppelinContext` objects in paragraphs with lots of stuff. Anyone knows any tip or trick to get it working?

Comment: Did you run all the cells in the notebook and see if the 4th paragraph was working? Many times if you restart zeppelin or the interpreter the context is lost.

Comment: Yes, I run all of them and only the 4th fails. I run 3rd again and it works. I remove all lines except the echos from the 4th and it works. Its strange.